# Show that if $|z|=1$ then $|e^z|>\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: complex-numbers

i knew that from modulus in complex,

$|e^z|=|e^{x+iy}|\\=|e^x.e^{iy}|\\=|e^x|.|cos(y)+isin(y)|\\=|e^x|.\sqrt{cos^2(y)+sin^2(y)}\\=|e^x|$

and from $$|z|=1\\\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1\\x^2+y^2=1$$

i don't know what to do from there, how can i prove it?

Comment: $e^x \ge e^{-1} > 1/3$, the latter because $e < 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, basically, you have shown that $|e^z| = e^x$, with $x$ being the real part of $z$, note that $x \in [-1,1]$, so $$e^x \geq e^{-1} \approx 0.3679 > \frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: thankyou so much!

Comment: @Ceciliads No worries!

Answer (score 2):

$\left| e^{z}\right|=e^x$ is minimized when $x$ is chosen to be the smallest possible value it can, and if $x^2+y^2=1$ then then least value for $x$ is $x=-1$ (corresponding to the point (-1,0)), at which point $\left| e^{z}\right|=e^{-1}\approx0.368>1/3$.

Comment: thankyou so much!